# If database record limit reached return to previous page with message

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I am building out our membership levels and each one has limits on how many records one can save to the database.  Someone on a [laracasts](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/does-laravel-or-eloquent-provide-an-easy-way-to-count-rows-across-all-tables) said I would want to check the limit against the membership level in an [observer](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#observers) and if the limit has been reached redirect them to the previous page and show an error.

This seems to be working except it redirects with the message that the limit has been reach AND creates the records.  Ideally it should not create the record if the limit has been reached.  I don't know what I am doing wrong, I also tried to `return false;` instead of `return back();` but that didnt work either.

(by the way if there is an easier way to do this I am all ears)

Here is my observer:

```
<?php 

namespace App\Observers;

use App\Company;
use Auth;
use Session;

class SubscriptionLimits {

    public function __construct(){
        $this->company =  Auth::user()->company_id;
    }

    public function creating()
    {
      try {
                $company = Company::find($this->company);

                $clients = \App\Client::where(['company_id' => $this->company])->count();
                $contacts = \App\Contact::where(['company_id' => $this->company])->count();
                $leads = \App\Lead::where(['company_id' => $this->company])->count();
                $opportunities = \App\Opportunity::where(['company_id' => $this->company])->count();
                $invoices = \App\Invoice::where(['company_id' => $this->company])->count();
                $estimates = \App\Estimate::where(['company_id' => $this->company])->count();
                $proposals = \App\Proposal::where(['company_id' => $this->company])->count();
                $projects = \App\Project::where(['company_id' => $this->company])->count();
                $tasks = \App\Task::where(['company_id' => $this->company])->count();
                $boards = \App\Board::where(['company_id' => $this->company])->count();
                $bulletins = \App\Bulletin::where(['company_id' => $this->company])->count();
                $cards = \App\Card::where(['company_id' => $this->company])->count();
                $lineitems = \App\LineItem::where(['company_id' => $this->company])->count();
                $notes = \App\Note::where(['company_id' => $this->company])->count();
                $timer = \App\Timer::where(['company_id' => $this->company])->count();
                $templates = \App\Template::where(['company_id' => $this->company])->count();
                $userExtra = \App\UserExtra::where(['company_id' => $this->company])->count();

                $count = $clients + $contacts + $leads + $opportunities + $invoices + $estimates + $proposals + $projects + $tasks + $boards + $bulletins + $cards + $lineitems + $notes + $timer + $templates + $userExtra;

                if($count >= 5 && !$company->subscriptions){ //Free tier throw error because limit is reached
                    //return false; //Works but throws error
                    Session::flash('error', 'You have reached your record limit, please <a href="/order">upgrade now</a> to continue');
                    return back();
                }

                if($company->subscribed('middle_tier_monthly_per_user') || $company->subscribed('middle_tier_annual_per_user')){
                    if($count > 10){ //If middle tier and limit is reached
                        //return false; //Works but throws error
                        Session::flash('error', 'You have reached your record limit, please <a href="/order">upgrade now</a> to continue');
                        return back();
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                Session::flash('error', 'You have reached your record limit, please <a href="/order">upgrade now</a> to continue');
                return back();
            }
    }

}
```

**UPDATE**
[Here is a video](https://youtu.be/rdJQFmGGEvk) of the issue, this should not let me create a record and should instead return the limit reached message and prompt me to upgrade.

Comment: First of all when you're catching the exception the message should be different. It's misleading to everyone if you claim that the error was that the limit was reached but it was in fact something else (e.g. the database is offline). (Also, `use Exception`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't redirect on observer. Observers are only meant to intercept the data before its written to the database.

You'll redirect on the controller where you're saving your data to the database.

In your controller:
`

```
function store(){
    if(!$model->save()) redirect()->back();
       return redirect()->to('#url');
}
```

`

Comment: Added a video which shows my issue, is your answer still the way to go?

Comment: That makes sense, How would I prevent the creation of the record in the database from the observer if limit is reached though ?

Comment: you can return false; and the data will not be stored in the database. Its the only way *not* to save on the database. However, you cannot redirect because its an event.

Answer (score 0):

Just dd() in each 'if' and let me know where is the condition failing by taking 1 extra record.

Comment: I did this initially, if I `dd()` it returns true (because I am a middle_tier_monthly_per_user and I have more than 10 records) . - It does indeed redirect, but still creates the record AND returns the message about the limit.  I assume this is because there is nothing "stopping" the record from being created so it still executes?  Is there a way to stop the event so the record is not created? I am updating the question with a video of whats going on.